# How would I loop this on Python?

Tags: python

How would I loop this code to make it so that the user inputs the number of friends they have, their names, and in the end, the program will be able to output the information? This is what I have so far, but I believe it's incorrect.

```
Friends = int(input("Please enter number of friends")
for i in range(Friends):
    Name = input("Please enter friend number 1:")
```

Comment: Append the names to a list. BTW, your prompt will say friend number 1 for every friend.

Comment: Is there a way to make it say friend number 2 after a loop?

Comment: These are all things you should learn from a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Append each name to a list, then print the list. And use string formatting to put an appropriate number in the prompt.

```
friendList = []
Friends = int(input("Please enter number of friends")
for i in range(Friends):
    Name = input("Please enter friend number %d: " % (i+1))
    friendList.append(Name)
print(friendList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a try using list comprehension:

```
Friends = int(input("Please enter number of friends :"))
Names = [input("Please enter friend number {}:".format(i)) for i in range(1,Friends+1)]
print(Names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop using the number of friends, and store the name for each of them:

```
friend_count = int(input("Please enter number of friends: "))
friend_list = []
for friend_index in range(friend_count):
    name = input("Please enter friend number {}: ".format(friend_index + 1))
    friend_list.append(name)

print(friend_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw_input, from the documentation

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

Code

```
name_array = list()
num_friends = raw_input("Please enter number of friends:")
print 'Enter Name(s): '
for i in range(int(num_friends)):
    n = raw_input("Name :")
    name_array.append((n))
print 'Names: ',name_array
```